# Modify array in typescript/angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to change an array of strings to an array of key-value pairs as shown below.
`["a","b"]` becomes `[{"Info":"a"},{"Info":"b"}]`

Any advice will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
const result = ['a', 'b'].map(item => ({ info: item });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control)**:

```
let array = ["a", "b"];

let mappedArray: Array<{
    info: string
}> = array.map(item: string => {
    return {
        info: item
    };
})
```